# Valid way to use isset in if {}

Tags: php, if-statement, get

I was wondering: I use this code:

```
if($_GET['rvr_filter_select'] == $qRows) {
    $sSelected = 'selected';    
}
```

But in this case when php doesnt get rvr_filter_select it gives a error of a undifined index rvr_filter select

Now I was wondering of this is a valid way to solve this problem. It doesnt output the error anymore but I dont know if it will work the same as the code above:

```
if(isset($_GET['rvr_filter_select']) == $qRows) {
    $sSelected = 'selected';    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
if(isset($_GET['rvr_filter_select']) && $_GET['rvr_filter_select'] == $qRows)
```

The isset function returns a boolean: true or false.

Answer (score 1):

Thats not going to work, because you will first validate if the value is set, this will be true of false and then compare it to $qrows, you should do both for best results..

```
if(isset($_GET['rvr_filter_select']) && $_GET['rvr_filter_select'] == $qRows) {
    $sSelected = 'selected';    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The isset function returns a boolean: true or false.

```
if(isset($$_GET) && isset($_GET['rvr_filter_select']) && $_GET['rvr_filter_select'] == $qRows){
    $sSelected = 'selected';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['rvr_filter_select']) && trim($_GET['rvr_filter_select']) == $qRows) {
    $sSelected = 'selected';    
}
else
{
}
```